# jQuery .flip() on a 2 Second Interval Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 words that I would like to flip on their x-axis on a 2 second interval (that repeats).

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
count = 0;
wordsArray = ["Quality", "Performance", "Solutions"];
setInterval(function () {
    count++;

    $("words").text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).flip({ axis: 'x' });

    }, 2000);
});
```

HTML:

```
<span id="words">Solutions</span>
```

Instead of flipping, nothing happens.

I am able to make the words fade in and out using this code:

```
$(function () {
count = 0;
wordsArray = ["Quality", "Performance", "Solutions"];
setInterval(function () {
    count++;
    $("#words").fadeOut(400, function () {
        $(this).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
    });
    }, 2000);
});
```

I have included:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/jquery.flip.js"></script>
```

.flip() comes from: https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/

I am missing something in the function to flip the words?

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser's console and what library did you include to do the flip? jQuery by default has no flip function.

Comment: On a side not I would suggest looking into scope and the usage of `var`

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question to include the library, comes from: https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/

Comment: Selector should be: $("#words")

Comment: You need to add a # to $('words'). I'm not familiar with flip but read their docs a bit more to get the animation going. It's simple to create a front and back but will take extra effort the have it dynamically switching between 3.

Comment: The # missing in the selector was it, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions for flip() wants child elements with classes of front and back.

Copied from https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/

```
<div id="card"> 
  <div class="front"> 
    Front content
  </div> 
  <div class="back">
    Back content
  </div> 
</div>
```

Try your html like

```
<span id="words"> 
  <span class="front"></span> 
  <span class="back"></span> 
</span>
```

and your javascript:

```
$(function () {
count = 0;
wordsArray = ["Quality", "Performance", "Solutions"];
setInterval(function () {
    count++;
    $("#words").text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).flip({ axis: 'x' });    
    }, 2000);
});
```